# The query builder in Visual Studio 2019 can not connect query any data from Oracle database

Tags: visual-studio, query-builder, vb.net-2010

**Issue description:**
VS crashes and reopens when opening query builder from within Table Adapter Configuration Wizard. The issue happens only when connecting to Oracle database and not with Sql Database.  The issue started happening after migrating from VS 2012 to VS 2019 and OS from Windows Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2022 Standard Version 21 H2.

**Environment:**
•   Windows Server 2022 Standard Version 21H2
•   Visual Studio 2019 v16.9
•   .NET Framework 3.5
•   VB .NET
•   Windows Forms Application

**Analysis from Microsoft:**

```
0:000> r
eax=00000004 ebx=00cfb468 ecx=00000000 edx=00b59000 esi=00cfb7c8 edi=0000000d
eip=77992c85 esp=00cf03d8 ebp=00cf03d8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00210206
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x15:
77992c85 f00fba3000      lock btr dword ptr [eax],0   ds:002b:00000004=????????
0:000> kbL
**# ChildEBP RetAddr      Args to Child **            
00 00cf03d8 1d9e4eb0     00000000 00cfb468 00cfb458 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x15
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
01 00cf03e8 1d9e309a     1da3a1e8 00cf4420 00000000 ociw32!opinit+0x2924
02 00cfb458 1d9e1143     0000000a 00cfb478 00cfb5c8 ociw32!opinit+0xb0e
03 1da3cd80 1d9e1143     00cfb7c8 1da264c4 0000000d ociw32!obndra+0x107
04 00cfb5c8 635c7070     6e65696c 724f5c74 656c6361 ociw32!obndra+0x107
```

Ociw32 which is seen in call stack is an Oracle's dll. It is passing a bad parameter to ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection which is the cause of crashing of Visual Studio.
**As the issue is caused by a 3rd party module, you will have to contact Oracle for further investigation.**

I expect I can use the query Builder from Visual Studio 2019 to query data from an Oracle database.